# Do Join on STRING_SPLIT but only under a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have something like this

```
-- @employees is a comma seperated list. Ex: 'E001,E002,E003'

SELCT * 
FROM MyTable mt
INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@employees, ',') dt
    ON dt.value = mt.EmployeeId
```

The inner join is being used like a WHERE clause, so that I only get the items that have the employeeIds I've passed in. However, I want to change it so that if I pass in an empty list, it does not do the join anymore.

So, how can I do this? Here is some pseudo-code to illustrate what I need:

```
SELCT * 
FROM MyTable mt
IF (@employees != '')
BEGIN
    INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@employees, ',') dt
        ON dt.value = mt.EmployeeId
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead, move the condition to the `where` and use:

```
SELCT mt.* 
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM STRING_SPLIT(@employees, ',') dt
              WHERE dt.value = mt.EmployeeId
             ) OR
      @employees IS NULL;
```

EDIT:

You might find that `UNION ALL` produces a better execution plan:

```
SELCT mt.* 
FROM MyTable mt JOIN
     STRING_SPLIT(@employees, ',') dt
     ON dt.value = mt.EmployeeId
UNION ALL
SELECT mt.*
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE @employees IS NULL;
```

Comment: Moving the STRING_SPLIT down into the WHERE clause seems to slow down the query by quite a lot. With a null @employees, it's actually still slower than the join version, even when using a list of thousands of employees. Is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: @Andrio . . . My guess is that SQL Server misses the optimization to parse the string only once -- and the repeated parsing slows down the query.  That is just a guess, but `UNION ALL` should address the performance issue.

Comment: For low rowcounts store in @temp variable table with primary key of comma values prior to evaluation (as I'm guessing these are unique) otherwise you can always use trusty #temp tables (Primary keys on temp tables do affect estimates and other aspects of the query plan)